# Sharepoint Widget Integration

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

The company I work for would like to allow widgets to be pulled from our application into a client's SharePoint instance.

The most straight forward way that I could fine is to create a .aspx page and send it over to the client.

This solution does not seem very scalable since every time changes are required to fix something like a bug, we would need to resend the file over.

Are there other solutions that people know of ?

I am considering an iframe where the first request is to do an SSO into our site and then display whatever the iframe is requesting.  Has anyone tried something like this below ?

Thanks.

-Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an iframe, I think a webpart (or administration page?) is more suitable (embedded in a SharePoint Solution).

Depending of the maintenance / update / information... you can code your webpart to get Data from a webservice (WCF) hosted in your company. So that you can perform some updates directly from your company.

You will only need to define the good WCF contract (that can be difficult)

You have also to check that the client's server can connect to your web service (for security reasons sometimes the admin say NO ...)